# How does the CSS Pseudo-Class :state() work?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:state) I read about the `:state()` pseudo-class, however the page doesn't help much. I've tried to find some information somewhere else but wasn't very lucky. Can someone explain to me, how this pseudo-class is used?

I'm not looking for explanations on how to use pseudo-classes in general. I understand how to use `:hover` or `:nth-child()` for example but I don't understand how you can use `:state();` like what to use as an argument. Maybe someone can give a quick example.

Comment: It's still in development and browser support is yet to be identified. :state() refers to a custom state of an element. Like focus, active are states which are provided by the browser itself. In the same way, you can make your custom state like DoubleClick, rightClick for your element, and attach CSS using the `:state()` i.e. :state(doubleClick).

Comment: Note that the MDN page suggests that `:state()` is not even for standard HTML Elements, but _specifically_ for Custom Elements: _"The `:state` CSS pseudo-class represents **any custom element** with the specified custom state"_.

Comment: The first link in the OP's post now no longer finds :state() - is it possible this functional pseudoclass no longer is in development?